# Scons Visualstudio, multiple build targets generates duplicate NMakeOutput tag

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scons

I use scons to output a MSVS project, using the (trimmed down) example below:

```
applicationProgramRelease = envRelease.Program(source = releaseObjs, target = "build/release.exe")
applicationProgramDebug = envDebug.Program(source = debugObjs, target = "build/debug.exe")

# generate msvs project
project = env.MSVSProject(target = 'application' + env['MSVSPROJECTSUFFIX'],
                srcs = (Glob('source/*.cpp', strings=True)),
                incs = (Glob('include/*.hpp', strings=True)),
                buildtarget = applicationProgramDebug + applicationProgramRelease,
                variant = ['debug', 'release'])
```

This generates a project, with both a debug and release build target. However it seems to ignore the multiple build targets inside the .vcxproj.

Inside visual studio I can build for both debug and release, which seems to work just fine, apart from the fact that in both in debug and release it launches the release.exe. Taking a close look at the .vcxproj I discovered that the NMakeOutput tag is containing the wrong executable

Below is the NMakeOutput tag for the release build target:

```
    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='release|Win32'">C:\OfflineProjects\scons\scons3_multipletargets\build\release.exe</NMakeOutput>
```

Which is correct as the release target should lauch release.exe. This is the tag for the debug build target:

```
    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='debug|Win32'">C:\OfflineProjects\scons\scons3_multipletargets\build\release.exe</NMakeOutput>
```

As you can see; the debug target launches release.exe which is wrong! Is this problem related to my Scons syntax, or is this an actual error inside the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with your SCons/Builder syntax. You want to specify the "runfile" parameter as well, for your two separate variants "Debug" and "Release". See also the description of the MSVSProject Builder in the Appendix B of the UserGuide http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html .

Comment: Thank you! Adding the line runfile = ['build/debug', 'build/release'] Fixed the issue! Cheers!